# Divs layout over stretch background

Tags: html, css

I would like some help on the simplest way to code this style of layout with div layers.

Here is roughly what I'm going for: https://40.media.tumblr.com/7b6495c85236f1defae135f8384bf56a/tumblr_nsi2j0PQiG1rt59iio1_1280.jpg

Basically I need the background to be separated into 4 different sections with content in the middle. The top pink and grey background will have a main banner image on top of the background. I also need to be able to place content in the grey area, it will be some kind of javascript (dont worry about the boxes, they are just there as placeholders).

Right below the first grey will be links aligning towards the right side and probably a search bar somewhere in there too. So I was thinking of using the same div for both the links and the javascript content.

The small boxes for links I will most likely use tables for but I'm not sure which div area to place that in.

The white area will have the main content with one sidebar. Please disregard the larger empty white boxes...I think I will be moving them to the sidebar instead. This area needs to stretch depending on amount of content.

The bottom grey area will be used for more text/links so this area too needs to stretch vertically depending on amount of content.

I'm still toying around with the layout so I'm looking for a basic div skeleton that I can start working with. I've never made a div layout with stretch backgrounds and contents on top so I don't know where to begin.

This is all I have so far:

```
body {  background-color: #ffffff;
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
text-align: justify;
cursor: default;    }

#pinkbackground {
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background:#ffbaba; }

#whitebackground {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background:#ffffff; }


#greybackground {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background:#e2e2e2; }


#greybackground2 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background:#e2e2e2; }

<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="pinkbackground">         
</div>

<div id="greybackground">
     <div id="content">
     </div>       
</div>

<div id="whitebackground">
     <div id="content">
     </div>       
</div>

<div id="greybackground2">
     <div id="content">
     </div>       
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you have already tried...

Comment: @Jennifer give me 5 mins I'll have a mock up for you.

Comment: @JordanDavis : seriously?? :p (*asking this after 15mins*)

Comment: @jennifer : please give us [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing what you have tried and whats the issue...that would help us, *help you* in better manner!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor I've already included the code of what I had so far. There isnt really any issue...just that I don't know where to go from there or whats the best way to overlap content.

Answer (score 1):

This is a skeleton for you to use, I can make it way more visually appealing if you want, let me know?

Screenshot:

[image]

Live instance of the code --> https://jsfiddle.net/j8jgovjz/1/

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div>
            <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
        </div>
        <div><input id="srchbar" type="search" placeholder="Search for anything..."></div>
        <div>
            <a href="">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="">Sign In</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="content">
        <aside id="sidebar"></aside>
        <section id="main"></section>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

}

nav{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;

    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    background: #E448A9;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
nav>div{
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center; 
}
#logo{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    margin-left: 1em;

    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    line-height: 1.43;  
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: Circular,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
nav>div{
    width: 50vw;    
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(1){
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(2){
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav>div:nth-of-type(3){
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav>div>a{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-self: center;
    align-self: center;

    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;

    margin: 0 .5em;
    padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-transition: background-color 100ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 100ms;
    transition: background-color 100ms;
}
nav>div>a:hover{
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
nav>div>a:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
nav>div>a:nth-of-type(2){
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);  
}
nav>div>a:nth-of-type(2):hover{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);  
}

#srchbar{
    height: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    border: none;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
}
#content{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    height: 400vh;
}
#sidebar{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;

    background: #ccc;
}
#main{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
}
footer{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;

    background: #5c5c5c;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
}
```

Comment: you are roughly 20mins late fella! :D

Comment: @JordanDavis thanks for the fast response! i might be able to work with this. Its not quite what I was going for but I appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: @Jennifer yea no problem, anything I missed you want me to add in? I'm updating it to give it a better visual appearance right now.

Comment: @JordanDavis the white boxes dont need to be at the top :) Im sorry if I confused you, I put them in the image when I was roughly trying to decide what I want the finished result to look like. Those will be replaced by images/links later.

Also, I would like a footer at the bottom with a text area. I'm also not sure why the text boxes for left center and right span the page. The content area will only be in the center...say 1000 px or something.

I think I need about 3 separate divs for the content. One for the top, one for the main, and one for the footer. Sorry for being difficult :)

Comment: @Jennifer Oh okay I'll take em out... I really good at interface design i'll show you a pretty cool layout, see if you like it.

Comment: @Jennifer take a look at the new layout I just updated the code and all the links... let me know what you think?